# Visual C++ profiler filtering by thread ID

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, profiling

I am trying to profile my C++ application, and am interested only in main thread's performance.

I am using CPU Sampling method. I am trying to filter my results based on thread ID. However, I cannot find a way to figure out thread ID for my main call stack from the profiler's report.

Is there a simple way to filter out other threads?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the "Processes" view, you can see the threads grouped per process, including an "ID" column. You should be able to identify your main thread there.